# How to export certain attachment files by Id?

Tags: data-export, backup

Is it possible in salesforce export only certain attachment files by Id? As I know It is possible to save all Attachments through Data Export. Or Export through Data Loader as binary encoded text but It is not what I need.

Comment: Once you have the files as exported from the data loader, you can manipulate it as you like. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @sfdcfox for example, I have a list of certain attachments IDs and I want to export only them in format wich can be used for import them back(It's a kind of back-up). But when we export attachment  by Data Loader, all attachments are represented as binary encoded text format and It is not possible to import them back, isn't it?

Comment: The Data Loader used to support that option, but does not appear to any longer. You could download an older version of the Data Loader, or use a third-party import wizard to do so., or write a script in Perl, Ruby, Python, etc to parse the data out for you.